# X86 32b assembly - using atoll

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Under Ubuntu 12.04., and using x86 32 bit assembly possibly with C libraries, I need to use a number n which is

```
 2^31 - 1 < n <= 2^63 -1
```

On my system, C ints are 32 bit; and long longs 64 bit. I know how to proceed after having the number, but am stuck on getting the number ready.

My planned approach was as follows:

```
 - store n as a string in the .data segment    

- use atoll (pushl $n_Str, call atoll)   

 - retrieve the converted value, and store it in two consecutive int-sized storage locations (taking note of likely little-endian storage)
```

As the usual 32 bit return value convention through %eax cannot apply (or only possibly through a pointer, which I have checked seems to not be the case (%eax points to inaccessible memory after)), I assumed the value might be in (%eax, %ebx). I checked all permutations of high/low assuming this were the case, but it doesn't seem to be (if it is, and I messed up, kindly point out the proper way). The man (and man 3) page for atoll doesn't help.

How do I retrieve the converted integer? If this approach is impossible (strtoll has the same issue), any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: I need the ll only as a dividend; hence if I get the low and high dword, I am fine. I need more than hand-translation though which would be easy for one run as I eventually read the ll in as a command line argument.

Comment: What kind of processing do you see when you look at the assembly source of a C program calling `atoll`?

Comment: @ssh:...good point: none. It didn't come to my mind to just do that. Hold on, will make test C file and check in gdb, which might solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to depend on calling convention and compiler. `__stdcall` functions return 64-bit integers in pairs in `EAX:EDX` registers. `__cdecl` functions return a pointer to stack to the integer on GCC. `__cdecl` functions on `Visual C++` return a pair in `EAX:EDX`.

Here is the source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/High-Level_Languages

Comment: Very useful, tyvm! Gdb for the test file I prepared (see above) seems to confirm this.